# Update one row using entity framework c#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I am working on a Windows Forms Application using C# and entity framework. I put all the products that the customer bought in DGVNewOrder. for evry product in the DGVNewOrder, I want to Update(by name) quantity in stock for every sold product . Here is the code I tried : '''

```
Product pro = new Product(); 

for (int i = 0; i < DGVNewOrder.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    string Soled_Product_name = DGVNewOrder.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    pro = db.Products.Where(d => d.Name == Soled_Product_name ).FirstOrDefault();
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(pro.QteInStock); // QteInStock befor selling 
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(DGVNewOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value); // the sold quantity 
    pro.QteInStock = y - x;  //  The remaining quantity after the sale
    db.Entry(pro).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

the problem here is The update does not happen to the quantity, but the names of all products are changed to the same name as the first product present in the DGVNewOrder
i also have tried this

```
string Soled_Product_name = DGVNewOrder.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          
Product c = (from w in db.Products
              where w.Name == Soled_Product_name
             select w).First();

int y = Convert.ToInt32(pro.QteInStock);
int x = Convert.ToInt32(DGVNewOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
c.QteInStock = y - x;

db.Entry(pro).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

but giving the same result

Comment: Try not creating the `pro` object before the loop and use use `var` before `pro = db.Products`, Not sure if this will help, but just a try

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that might cause this to happen. Perhaps the problem is caused by other parts of the code. Are you changing the loaded products anywhere else? It would be better if you can provide a [repro] so we can help you spot the problem.

Comment: Don't modify the internal state of EF (`db.Entry(pro).state` line).   EF knows just fine which properties have been changed, without you telling it.

Comment: do you see the same name in all products on the database table? or in your DataGridView? The posted code is not enough to reproduce the problem mate.

Comment: the same result @Sowmyadhar Gourishetty   @ Neil

Comment: Can you check what is the value that you are getting in `Convert.ToInt32(DGVNewOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value)`, if this is `zero` the previous and new value will be same

Comment: yes i do @Mongzhu

Comment: when i used the debugger the compiler does not exceed this line of code                                                                    
                          ```    Product c = (from w in db.Products
                                          where w.Name == Soled_Product_name
                                           select w).First(); ```    @ Sowmyadhar Gourishetty

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a control that shows elements of a collection, like a DataGridView, a ListView, it is usually not a good idea to edit the items in the control directly. One of the reasons for this, is that you need to actively fetch changed items from the control. If the display of the control changes, for instance, the order of the columns changes, or the order of the rows in your DataGridView, you have to actively find out what has changed.

It is way easier to use DataBinding for this. Put the items that need to be displayed in a `BindingList<T>`, and assign this to the `DataGridView.DataSource`.

`DataGridViewColum.DataPropertyName` contains the name of the property of `<T>` that should be displayed in the column. Whenever the operator edits a value and accepts it, your get notified that your BindingList has been changed. You don't have to read the DataGridView anymore, you automatically know that the complete DataGridView is updated in the BindingList. Even Added or Removed Lines are in the BindingList

Example:

```
class OrderLine
{
    public int Id {get; set;}           // primary key of the OrderLine
    public int ProductId {get; set;}    // foreign key to the Product in this OrderLine
    public string ProductDescription {get; set;}
    public decimal ProductPrice {get; set;}
    public int NrOfItems {get; set;}
    public decimal TotalPrice => this.ProductPrice * this.NrOfItems;
}
```

You want a DataGridView that shows the ProductId / ProductDescription / ProductPrice / NrOfItems / TotalPrice.

Operatos can add new OrderLines in your DataGridView, or remove OrderLines. They can't change the ProductId / ProductDescription / ProductPrice, but they can change the NrOfItems.

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

// Add columns. This is some tedious work, usually it is best to let visual studio designer
// do this
dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn()
{
     Name = "columnProductId",
     DataProperty = nameof(OrderLine.ProductId),
     ReadOnly = true;
     ...
}
```

etc for all your columns.

Now to fill your datagridview with some initial items:

```
IList<OrderLine> initialOrderLines = ...
var actualOrderLines = new BindingList<OrderLine(initialOrderLines);
dgv.DataSource = actualOrderLines;
```

Use the default constructor if you have no initial order lines

And presto, all your columns are filled with the actualOrderLines. During editing this collection is automatically updated. If the operator adds a new Line, it is automatically initialized with a default OrderLine, or if you want, you can provide an OrderLine if you subscribe to event `BindingList.OnAddingNew`.

Finally, after the operator has finished making all his changes, he presses a button:

```
void OnButtonReady_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // you can be certain the the BindingList is up-to-date
    // you don't have to fetch the items from the DataGridView anymore.
    this.UpdateStock(this.actualOrderLines);
}

private void UpdateStock(IEnumerable<OrderLine> actualOrderLines)
{
     foreach (OrderLine orderLine in actualOrderLines)
     {
         // TODO: update the stock
     }
}
```

The nice thing is: if the Columns order is changed, or the Rows are sorted, then this has no effect on your actualOrderLines. If in future you decide to add or remove columns: no problem, you only know that your information is in actualOrderLines, who cares how it is shown to the operator, or how he edits the information.

One final nice thing: if you want to order the columns by a simple mouse click on the headers, consider [Nuget Package BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView)

Instead of `BindingList<T>` use `BindingListView<T>`

```
var initialOrderLines = ...
BindingListView<OrderLine> actualOrderLines = new BindingListView<OrderLine>(initialOrderLines);
this.dgv.DataSource = actualOrderLines;
```

And bingo: whenever you click on the headers, the items are ordered in ascending or descending order by the column property. Even the glyph (little arrow that shows sort order) is shown correctly.

Comment: You've put in some of your time for my problem that you are an expert and you've taught me a lot here.:@Harald Coppoolse